# How to export color dodge effect from Photoshop or Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I created color dodge effect in Illustrator, and now I want to save two png files, one for background and one for color dodge effect, but when I do it it has a black background. How can it be done?

[image: used dodge tool]

This is what my images looks like (full image on right, colour-dodge-only image on left):

[image: full]
[image: only dodge]

The software we are using to display the image has no function like color dodge. Is there a way to save color dodge effect in png file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PNGs cannot be exported with blending options embedded. You'll have to use a program that supports blending options in order to get the same effect.

**********  Edit  **********

You can get something similar by making your radial gradient go from about 75% opacity in the middle to 0% opacity on the outside, It won't be exactly the same, but it will be closer than what you've got.

Answer (score 1):

You want to export two PNG Files and will import or open in some other software like Photoshop or After Effects to gain this effect again.
For this you export two Images different with Transparent PNG's and open in other software keep them in two layers and mark above layer as color dodge and you will get the same effect.

now you can animate or edit in After effects and Photoshop individually.
Thanks

Comment: The software we are using has no function like color dodge.. Is there a way to save color dodge effect in png file?

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, you can't save blending modes to a .png. You can try to imitate it, but there are some severe limitations.

As Circle B suggests, you could use a regular gradient, the limitation of this is that it will inevitably dull any colour behind it, hence making the background look dirty rather than illuminated:

(Comparison shows your dodge on left, then the transparent png on the right)

[image: Transparent png] 
[image: Comparison of dodge layer (left) vs transparent png(right)]

You can get a little more creative with the transparent png, but at the expense of severely limiting the utility of the image:

[image: Transparent png] 
[image: Comparison of dodge layer (left) vs transparent png(right)]

If you look at the png on a [black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXwE3.png) you can see there are a bunch of **major** limitations:

1. It is specific to one background.
2. It can't be resized.
3. It'll only be reusable on patterned backgrounds since it must be aligned with the repeating pattern of the image (in this case at intervals of 13px horizontally, and 12px vertically)

If you did think that technique could still be of use, you'd do it like so:

- Create the background layer.
- I took your dodge layer from the question (set to "Dodge")
- Duplicate the background, place it on top of the dodge layer and set it to "Subtract".
- Merge those layers so they become rasterised
- Use Color -> Color To Alpha, and select black as the colour.

But I'm not convinced there would be a good reason to..

Comment: pft, wrote this yesterday when answer posting was broken. tl;dr theres no nice solution to the problem.